# BotFramework: PromptDialog.Choice no longer returns partial matches

Tags: c#, botframework

PromptDialog.Choice used to return partial matches, but after upgrading to BotFramework 3.8.1 this is no longer the case.
The underlying PromptRecognizer does have the option `PromptRecognizeChoicesOptions.AllowPartialMatches` but that option is not exposed to the Dialog. (`PromptChoice.TryParse` calls the recognizer without options)

Is there a way to allow partial matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this and good catch! You are right, the offended line is [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/db2b8f860a3d8f7744a378930f93c4b0baa97978/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L973) when comparing with Node ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/17e6381d61133c75573d5547635f8d527422b61b/Node/core/src/dialogs/PromptChoice.ts#L103-L104)).

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/pull/2851) to fix this.